# How to read and write PHP code to a PHP file

Tags: php, fwrite

I have code of following form inside my PHP file

```
<?php
$my_array = array("ke1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");
?>
```

now I want to edit this file dynamically through my php script and make it of following form

```
<?php
 $my_array = array("ke1" => "value1", "key2" => "value3");
?>
```

What will be the best approach to do this?

Comment: To stop trying to programatically edit program code and just use a database or a data file with a sensible data format like JSON.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, what is your final objectif ?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply write a normal file with the code

```
$value1 = 10;
$value2 = 30;

$file = fopen('myfile.php', 'w');
frwite($file, '<?php $my_array = array("ke1" => "'. $value1 .'", "key2" => '. $value2 .'); ?>');
fclose($file);
```